# Google app engine: parse a sql database

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, python-2.7, sqlite

I have a MyFile entity with sql db file:

```
class MyFile(ndb.Model):
  data = ndb.BlobProperty()
```

data property store sql db file. So in requestHandler I need to parse this file.
I am trying to using standard sqlite3 library, but getting error on gae side:

```
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

With `PyDbLite` library I am getting error too:

```
    from PyDbLite.SQLite import Database, Table
File "libs/PyDbLite/SQLite.py", line 81, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite
```

Is there any way to parse sql database in goggle app engine?

I know that gae uses NoSQL datastore, I just need to handle sql db file.

Comment: have you made these modules available to your app engine application? If they are not uploaded when you deploy, you won't be able to import them (even if it all seems to work locally). You can add most pure-python and many not pure modules to your gae app.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood Yes I uploaded additional library, but still have this error.

Comment: perhaps it's unavailable on GAE due to it's C-components then, not sure.

Comment: You cannot use libraries that use the filesystem on aopengine. Upload the db to google cloud sql which works with appengine

Comment: You should be able to READ files uploaded with your app, just not write them. I think the cause is more likely that the module isn't in the python path when deployed.

Answer (score 0):

The module `_sqlite3` may be in your python path locally, but when deployed, the module cannot be found. You can debug your python path by printing it when in production and making sure the module is visible on that path (keep in mind that any old file or folder isn't considered a module ready for import by python, it needs to have `__init__.py`).

The only reason you would receive that error is if you either

A) failed to upload the module you're using as part of your project, mistakenly believing that since it was visible to your local python code it should be visible when deployed

or

B) failed to reference the uploaded module correctly. My comments in the first paragraph should help you debug this case.